# Can you copy colored text from C# Console?

Tags: c#, .net

I made a little program that makes your input text colorful. A different color of the rainbow for each char.

here is the code:

```
            foreach (char letter in char_array)
            {
                switch (random_int)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                        break;
                }
                Console.Write(letter);
                Thread.Sleep(20);
                random_int = random.Next(1,7);
            }
```

and it works fairly well. I was just wondering if I can copy the colorful text and paste it as is, with the colors.

Comment: The copy/paste part aspect is really up to the terminal/console - how it got there (whether through C# code or something else) is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: but... can you?

Comment: Can you what? Basically it sounds like you're asking something about the console, not about C#... so this is more a SuperUser question than a Stack Overflow question, and may well depend on the console/terminal that you're using.

Comment: This is not a coding problem. It is a problem on how the console or terminal sends the data to the clipboard. If the `cmd.exe` does not send the information formatted, you are out of luck. YOu may consider asking in SuperUser

Comment: which console/terminal should I use then?